# SharePoint Validation Settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column-formula, validation, formula

I have a drop down with Not Started, In Progress, Completed, No Longer Needed as different options.

I want to require In Progress Comments to be filled in when In Progress is selected. When Completed is selected I want Completed Comments to be filled in.

Not started and No longer Needed do not require any comments to be filled in

Comment: What is the data type of "Progress Comments" and "Completed Comments" fields? Single line of text or multiple lines of text?

Answer (score 0):

If the data type of "Progress Comments" and "Completed Comments" fields is "single line of text", you can use list validation formula like:

```
=NOT(OR(AND([Status] = "In Progress", ISBLANK([Progress Comments])), AND([Status] = "Completed", ISBLANK(Completed Comments))))
```

---

If the data type of "Progress Comments" and "Completed Comments" fields is "multiple lines of text", you cannot use list validation formula as "multiple lines of text" fields are not supported in SharePoint formulas.

If you are using SharePoint online modern experience, you have to customize the list form using Power Apps to apply validation for list form fields.